# How to choose the sample size

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, experiment-design, sample-size, statistical-power

How do I choose a sample size for a multiple factors irrigation experimental research? Here is what I mean, I want to compare the effect of precision irrigation and conventional irrigation on crop yield and irrigation water management. The research involved three factors with two levels for each, irrigation type(drip-irrigation, soil sensor based-irrigation), corn variety (EVDT97STRW variety and FAABA variety), fertilization level (Low and High Nitrogen level). As I'm planning to analyze data doing an ANOVA how could ı design block? And what sure be my sample size ?

Comment: Hi, are you interested in interactions between the factors or just main effects? R packages pwr and Superpower may work for you.

Comment: Hi - welcome to Cross Validated. I presume from this, you want to test if certain types of irrigation etc. have a certain effect. Define your hypotheses. Once you have that, use power analysis (e.g. by hand or via R's `pwr` package) to determine the sample size required, given an guessed effect size and desired confidence level.